# Error al transformar una columna de NumPy arrays - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, array, numpy, scikit-learn

Tengo un DataFrame con con una columna que contiene NumPy arrays.

Cada array tiene un shape (48, 48) —son imágenes de 48x48px.

```
X_train['array']

3592    [[60, 64, 65, 61, 56, 56, 59, 60, 53, 73, 88, ...
4352    [[80, 131, 131, 115, 125, 112, 106, 144, 221, ...
5974    [[162, 73, 54, 50, 64, 84, 52, 42, 54, 45, 42,...
2627    [[28, 25, 21, 16, 10, 10, 17, 25, 41, 67, 98, ...
6150    [[186, 146, 22, 24, 21, 28, 20, 45, 77, 95, 10...
                              ...                        
3772    [[166, 18, 11, 12, 7, 2, 6, 3, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, ...
5191    [[50, 39, 24, 16, 16, 17, 17, 15, 14, 12, 11, ...
5226    [[21, 19, 25, 34, 35, 29, 30, 39, 44, 43, 43, ...
5390    [[157, 166, 179, 159, 148, 161, 166, 179, 166,...
860     [[61, 63, 69, 83, 93, 85, 88, 110, 110, 126, 1...
Name: array, Length: 4940, dtype: object
```

Escribo lo siguiente:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
```

Si trato de transformar la columna entera, ocurre lo siguiente:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-ff7314093eb3> in <module>
----> 1 X_train_array_escalado = scaler.fit_transform(X_train['array'])


ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Sin embargo, si escalo los arrays uno por uno, no tengo problema. Voy a escalar el primero (índice 3592), por ejemplo:

```
array_escalado = scaler.fit_transform(X_train['array'][3592])
array_escalado

array([[-0.81065487, -0.62906812, -0.4790824 , ..., -0.88472034,
        -0.75704033, -0.157433  ],
       [-0.81065487, -0.70344071, -0.57180802, ..., -0.91466856,
        -0.87952775, -0.34955463],
       [-0.85191832, -0.77781329, -0.66453365, ..., -1.00451322,
        -1.1245026 , -0.92591952],
       ...,
       [ 1.16999074,  0.8211973 ,  1.14361604, ...,  0.88222466,
         0.67197962,  0.16276971],
       [ 1.25251765,  0.8211973 ,  1.00452761, ...,  0.76243178,
         0.63115048,  0.35489134],
       [ 1.00493694,  0.63526584,  0.77271354, ...,  0.67258711,
         0.54949219,  0.41893189]])
```

Answer (score 0):

**He logrado resolver el problema de la siguiente manera**

```
X_train_scaled = X_train['array'].apply(scaler.fit_transform).values

X_test_scaled = X_test['array'].apply(scaler.transform).values
```